# Получение доступа ко всем RadioButton`ам во время работы программы

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, рефлексия

Допустим у меня в программе используется очень много RadioButton-ов. Возможно ли с помощью рефлексии(или еще как-то), во время работы программы получить доступ сразу ко всем. Мне это нужно чтобы сделать `IsChecked = false;` сразу для всех.

Comment: Ну например, общий стиль должен сработать. Хотя непонятно, зачем вам такое, если у вас используется MVVM. (А если нет, то почему?)

Comment: ищите все контролы по маске `Object.GetType().ToString() == RadioButton` или что -то в этом духе и ставьте им нужный параметр

Comment: @VladD, Ток начал изучение WPF, пока ни стили, ни MVVM не разбирал.

Comment: @Dmitry, где искать контролы по маске?

Comment: @Lightness вы как ко вью обращаетесь? точно не помню как там в XAML, но как мне кажется можно получить все контролы на форме  и задать им нужный атрибут. особенно использовав такую конструкцию `o.Where(a=>a.GetType().ToString().Equals("RadioButton"))`, с синтаксисом мог напутать, ночь, пятница, пиво

Comment: @Lightness: Ну так вы бы выучили, сразу много вопросов отпадёт.

Comment: @VladD, я в процессе обучения. И я нашел ответ на мой вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
foreach (RadioButton tb in FindVisualChildren<RadioButton>(window))
{

}
```

[Решение взято отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)